# Distances between same numbers in list using single for loop

Tags: python, algorithm, time-complexity, computer-science

I have an assignment to get distances of every occurrence of same number in string and its time complexity should be O(n) so it shouldn't use nested for loops.

For example if my string contains "100101" and I need to get distances between ones it's total distance would be 10. (Since first and second has distance of 3, first and last has 5 and second and last has 2).

I do get the correct answers using nested for loops but I don't understand how this should be implemented without nested loops.

My current code:

```
def pairs(s):
    array = []
    total = 0

    for i in range(len(s)):
        if s[i] == "1":
            array.append(i)

    for k in reversed(array):
        array.remove(k)
        for j in reversed(array):
            total += k - j
        
    return total



if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(pairs("100101")) # 10
    print(pairs("101")) # 2
    print(pairs("100100111001")) # 71
```

Comment: Iterate forwards and have your code "remember" the last position where the character has been encountered. Use a dict if you have to do this for multiple characters.

Comment: Where is this from? Is it online somewhere for testing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be indeed computed in linear time (I adapted the classic greedy algorithm used to compute the sum of Manhattan distances of sorted points):

```
def pairs(numbers, target):
    result = s = i = 0
    for j, n in enumerate(numbers):
        if n == target:
            result += (j * i - s)
            s += j
            i += 1
    return result
```

Some examples:

```
>>> pairs('100101', '1')
10
>>> pairs('100101', '0')
6
>>> pairs('100010101', '1')
26
```

Comment: This: `result, s, i = 0` is an error. Needs to be `result, s, i = 0,0,0`

Comment: @dawg I'm sorry, but I really don't know why it's an error. Can you please help me understand why?

Comment: The form `x,y,x=0` is a tuple unpacking. You can either do `x=y=z=0` which is a serial assignment or `x,y,z=(some iterable that unpacks to three values...)` This is other wise fantastic!

Comment: @dawg Ok thanks a lot for the explanation! Can you maybe point me to some good resource that explains why tuple unpacking is wrong but it's also working in practice? I'm kinda of confused, and want to know more about this.

Comment: [Here for unpacking](https://treyhunner.com/2018/03/tuple-unpacking-improves-python-code-readability/) is one and [Here for extending unpacking](https://peps.python.org/pep-3132/)

Comment: Btw, you can make your loop *slightly* more efficient with `for j in (i for i, n in enumerate(numbers) if n==target):` and eliminating the `if n == target:` inside.

Comment: What's the meaning of your variables? And how can it be O(n) when n is the name for each element? (I.e., better call them something else.)

Answer (score 3):

Another variant:

```
def pairs(s):
    total = ones = distance = 0
    for digit in s:
        if digit == '1':
            ones += 1
            total += distance
        distance += ones
    return total
```

`ones`: The number of 1s seen so far.

`total`: The sum of distances between the 1s seen so far.

`distance`: the sum of distances of previous 1s to the current position.

When you come across another 1, count it (`ones += 1`) and add its sum of distances to all previous 1s to the overall total (`total += distance`).

When you move to the next position, you move one position away from all 1s seen so far, hence `distance += ones`.